# Unifi Dream Machine, UK use, dsl

Tags: ubiquiti

First, I feel I have to say, I'm very new to Networking. I've used my ISP provided router for years and I'm only now looking into ways to improve my Wifi signal, network security etc.

So, I'm thinking about buying a UniFi Dream Machine. Having read lots of positive reviews ([Scott Helm](https://scotthelme.co.uk/my-ubiquiti-home-network/), [Troy Hunt](https://www.troyhunt.com/ubiquiti-all-the-things-how-i-finally-fixed-my-dodgy-wifi/), [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0gOoivOXoE) from Pete Matheson), but being new to this area, I have questions.

The Dream Machine does not have a dsl input port, like my current ISP provided router...so how do I connect a Dream Machine to my phone socket? Do I need to keep my ISP provided modem/get a converter/buy a separate modem? As I understand it the Dream Machine isn't a modem, its WAN port wants an Ethernet cable.

I understand if, say, I had fiber to the cabinet (FTTC) I'd have a different "box" in my house that I could just plug the Dream Machine into via an Ethernet cable.

**update**

My equipment: Bright Box 1 (R) Wireless Router

My ISP: EE

Comment: It depends on what the current ISP-provided box is. Some you can just dumb down to 'pure modem' mode. The Virgin box can do that, idk about others. If not, you'll need a new modem - but check with your ISP to see if a 3rd party modem will even register. Many UK ISPs will not let you use your own equipment.

Comment: Added an update with my router details

Comment: Thanks. Not a structure I know, so can't add any more, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some terminology and diagrams:

## All-In-One Router

The [EE Bright Box 1](https://shop.ee.co.uk/broadband/ee-bright-box-router) is a typical "*Home Router*", which means that includes all of the components necessary to facilitate the customer. ISPs generally provide these as they can have better control over the configuration, and customers don't generally like having multiple boxes. They exist for both Cable and xDSL connections.

They are actually a number of devices in one unit:

- xDSL Modem
- Router
- Switch
- Wireless Access Point

[image: diagram of aio router's internals]

## Separate Router and Modem (or Media Converter)

The [UniFi Dream Machine](https://store.ui.com/collections/unifi-network-routing-switching/products/unifi-dream-machine) aligns with what has been previously marketed as a "*Cable Router*" - which fundamentally means that it doesn't include a modem, and the user will generally require either an external modem (e.g: xDSL or [DOCSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCSIS), etc...) or media converter (i.e: FTTP).

FTTP customers will likely have this setup - I've not yet seen a consumer / home router with built-in optics for FTTP customers, but I imagine that they'll be around in the not too distant future.

[image: diagram of modem, plus router's internals]

## Routers in "*Bridge Mode*"

Many DSL routers support what is known as "*Bridge Mode*" - where only the modem remains functional, and all of the other internal components are disabled.

This allows you to use their hardware to provide the underlying connection, and your own hardware to manage your internal network.

[image: diagram of aio router in bridge mode, plus customer router]

---

## Summary

Unfortunately, it looks like it is **not** possible to configure the EE Bright Box 1 into "*Bridge Mode*", meaning that you have two options available.

### Keep the Bright Box

Keep using the Bright Box as it is, and use the Dream Machine as a second (internal) router... this comes with some negative points:

- The Dream Machine may not be able to accurately determine its public IP address - it may instead report the IP address that the Bright Box's DHCP server gave it. This could affect things like Dynamic DNS services that it may offer, as well as reporting in the UI
- Any port forwarding will need configuration on both routers (unless you are able to configure a DMZ on the Bright Box)
- Routing and address conflicts will need to be carefully managed between the Bright Box and Dream Machine (i.e: they can't both use `192.168.0.0/24`), which can lead to confusion when things don't work.
- You're adding a step to the path of *all* internet-bound traffic, meaning that latencies may rise.

### Replace the Bright Box

Instead, you could purchase another xDSL modem, such as the DrayTek Vigor 130, and replace the Bright Box entirely.

This is the route I'd suggest that you take, and it aligns with the second diagram above. You may even improve your connection stability and speeds by replacing the modem built into the Bright Box as well.

Comment: Very useful. I'll update this with how I progress. I'm looking at some less "enterprise" level option to improve my home network now, given my lack of experience in this space

Comment: update - I decided to trial the [NETGEAR Nighthawk whole home mesh (WiFi 6)](https://www.netgear.co.uk/home/products/networking/nighthawk-mesh/mk62.aspx) , but was disappointed with its connectivity to various devices and the coverage was no better than a basic WiFi extender. So sent it back.